pronoun (etc) used to refer back to (overtly) a string of verbs
I am drafting the dedication below, which includes a list of adjectives:

Never stop building, searching, and asking why. It will take you to amazing places.

I'm questioning whether "It" is correct to describe the list, or if it should "They", "These things" or other - any thoughts would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

You probably mean verbs, not adjectives.

I can't pin down why, but "it" as a way of referring to the list feels a little off to me. "This will take you to amazing places" feels more idiomatic to me.

Yes; 'This' works very well, referring to the whole discipline of 'building, searching, and asking why' (the logical ordering might end with 'building' but this would lose the cadence). 'It' can do the same job as 'this' ('It's the Simpsons') but is less than stately.

@user888379 It's because "building, searching, and asking why" is not generally parsed as a single action that could be referred to with "it" - they are three separate actions. The use of "it" may sound more natural if the verbs are connected as a single phrase, like "Don't stop zigging and zagging, it can take you places".

You can also avoid the problem by saying: Never stop building, searching, and asking why. You will reach amazing places.

@user888379 Funny but I feel OK with "it". In my mind, they've combined the actions into a single collective.

Your search for the kind of it is misdirecting you, blocking your view of the right question, not the right answer.
It would be better to say
Never stop building, searching, and asking why. Then You will go to amazing places.
After all, it is You that is doing the building, searching and asking why. Since  you had to ask.

Or This will etc.


Never stop building, searching, and asking why. Ø will take you to amazing places.

Ø = 'They' or 'these' could only be chosen with more nounal ing-forms (traditionally 'gerunds'):

Searching, asking why, creating ... they / this (seeing the process as a whole and using notional agreement) will take you to amazing places. The 'never stop' of the original disallows this choice.

Ø = 'It' to refer tangentially to the whole process is probably marginally acceptable, on the other hand.
Ø = 'This' to refer tangentially to the whole process Xing ('Never stop Xing', where X is an imagined verb covering the whole process) feels more idiomatic to me as well as user888379.
Ø = 'Such determination' is obviously less extragrammatical, but loses punch. Often the case.
A rewrite like

Never stop building, searching, and asking why ... and you will reach amazing places. (Or fev's variant) is perhaps the best solution.


I feel ok with your "It", because I'm reading it as referring to the whole exhortation "Never stop...".
See for instance this sentence:

Always avoid watching screens before bedtime. It will make you sleep better.

The "It" is clearly referring to the main clause "Always avoid", not to the subordinate "watching". Or at least it's having an expletive role, substituting for the whole concept of "[Following this advice] will make...".
By the way, this sentence also works and –despite using the opposite adverb– has the same meaning, because "It" switches its antecedent:

Always avoid watching screens before bedtime. It will make you sleep badly.

In this case, the same "It" can be matched, from context, to the subordinate, "watching". That's because we know from context that the speaker wouldn't give a suggestion that is intentionally detrimental to the listener.
In other words, what "It" refers to is decided from context, and in your case "Never stop" is what I'd pick up as the most natural antecedent.
